# How to view error logs when mysql server is not starting in lampp

Tags: mysql, lampp

I am running `lampp` stack and I need to connect a `php` app it to the `MySql` server. But `MySql` database service is not starting and I have no idea why. When I look at the `Application log` I find no information regarding `MySql` after `Starting MySQL Database...` message.

[image]

On the other hand, the `Manage Servers` tab shows that the service has just stopped.
[image]

As stated earlier the main issue is that I cannot find what the problem is since the log is not providing me with any information. What can I do to figure it out? If there was an error shouldn't it be displayed in the `Application log`? Is there anywhere else where I can view the log in more detail?

Comment: Read it all, but I started you at [Where are mysql logs on Linux](https://likegeeks.com/mysql-on-linux-beginners-tutorial/#Where_are_MySQL_logs_on_Linux)

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is not a standalone MySql install. I have installed it with lampp. That is why I cannot find the log in that location.

Comment: DO you mean you installed XAMPP